# Wake up MCU with radio signal using a battery

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, low-battery

Currently I have a project that runs with the chip from Arduino (Atmega328p).

This is what it does:

1. It wakes up.
2. Powers the [NRF24L01 module.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LX47OCY) And it configures it to only send one packet

```
radio.begin();
radio.setRetries(0, 1); // set retries to 1. that way it goes to sleep faster!

// some random address that I pick. The receiver is listening on this same address
// currently this mcu is the transmitter in order to save energy
radio.openWritingPipe(0xE2E2E2E2E2E2);
```

3. Sends a packet

```
// #define RADIO_CMD_WAKE_UP 200
char msgToSend = RADIO_CMD_WAKE_UP;
bool wasMessageSent = radio.write(&msgToSend, 1);
```

4. If `wasMessageSent==true` it means the receiver was listening in order to wake us up
5. Else if `wasMessageSent==false` power off radio and go to sleep with a watch dog timer in order to wake up again in 2 seconds.

The nice thing about the nrf24 radio module is that when sending a packet you get a confirmation. So at the beginning everything is backwards, the transmitter is the receiver. So in order to wake up the receiver (it is the tranmitter at the beggining) I will have to make the tranmitter listen for 2 seconds until it receives a wake up packet. Once it receives that packet they both switch and now the receiver does not go to sleep and is waiting for commands to execute because it is running from a battery.

This solution works great because the atmega328p chip uses only 3 uA when in sleep mode! and when awake it uses 15 mA. It takes 12 ms to send the packet. This means that if I use a 1000mAh battery my project will run for over a year. So basically it uses 3 uA for 2 seconds and 15mA for 12ms.

**My question is how can I use a faster solution where I don't have to sleep for 2 seconds?** It will be amazing that I can wake up my receiver in less than a second.

For example I been trying to consider BLE (Bluetooth low energy). So when researching into BLE I am thinking about buying this:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B088BNWX6T/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088BNWX6T)

Or this

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07X4D7BKF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07X4D7BKF)

Or this

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07MBLVHH8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MBLVHH8)

**On the specs of those BLE devices I am not able to find out if I am able to receive data meanwhile on sleep mode**. Those devices consume very little current ~ 3mA. But in order for my battery to last for over a year I need to be in the micro amps range. Those devices consume micro-amps when in sleep mode. **But how can I know if they can receive data meanwhile on sleep mode?** I have not been able to find that information.

Another solution that I been thinking about is to get the STM32 (blue pill) that is much faster than arduino and maybe with that mcu I would be able to send an NRF24L01 packet in 4ms instead of 12ms. That way I would be able to sleep for only 1 second instead of 2 having my battery last the same amount of time.

Comment: This website https://www.geekstips.com/battery-life-calculator-sleep-mode/ will make the calculation. It comes to a total of 2 years.  Sorry my battery is only 1000mAh.

Comment: True @pasabaporaqui even if I get a faster board it will probably take the same amount of time. I have to wait for the NRF module to send back a response.

Comment: I measured 12ms based on this question @pasabaporaqui: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/85546/can-you-use-the-millis-function-to-determine-how-long-it-takes-to-run-the-setu